# Common sense answer to the question but I cannot justify it

Tags: probability

I was thinking about the generalisations we tend to make. For example if we meet 500 random people in a town of 50000 for example and they all had blue skin, not seeing the rest we would probably conclude that most likely everyone had blue skin but can we be certain that this is the case based on the data gathered?

So Just out of curiosity. There are only black or white ribbons. Not knowing the ratio of black to white ribbons. If one selects randomly out of a 100, 99 ribbons and they happened to be all black ribbons, is it more likely that the last ribbon is black? It seems like common sense that it is but I can't find a reason to justify it. If so why?

By the way I am not assuming that the chance of picking the ribbons as black or white is 50/50. First of all, I do assume that these are all the ribbons that exist. And that there can be only a black or white ribbon. However, the ratio of them is not assumed.

Comment: You need to have some notion of what the possible combinations were to begin with.

Comment: Sorry I mean if before you found out they could have been all white, 99 white one black, 98 white 2 black etc, until all being black.

Comment: We need more context to understand the question. But consider also the case of flipping a fair coin 99 times and getting all heads. It does **not** mean that the 100th flip is more likely to be head as well.

Comment: I was thinking about the generalisations we tend to make. Let think that if we meet 500 random people in a town of 50000 for example and they all had blue skin, not seeing the rest we would probably conclude that everyone had blue skin but can we be certain that it is highly likely that this is the case?

Comment: You might be interested in reading about [Laplace's Rule of Succession](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_succession)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is "no", mathematically. I should point out, I am assuming some context to the problem: that the bag is filled with $100$ ribbons, white and black, with equal probability of each ribbon being white or black.

I think you need to first philosophically examine the reason you doubt it, before you examine why my answer is true. You're applying a type of inference known as "induction" (this is different from mathematical induction). Induction is where we observe a trend in the world, one that occurs predictably, and we conclude that it will continue to occur.

For example, every day, the sun rises in the East. Can we conclude that the sun will rise in the East tomorrow? You could argue about the rotation of the Earth, but who's to say that will continue? The laws of physics? And how long do we think they'll last? etc, etc.

Generally speaking, if we observe a strong trend in the real world, we assume it will continue, unless we have some good reason to think it will not. One could imagine "possible worlds" where the Earth might simply stop rotating one day, for no particular reason at all, after rotating for billions of years. Why not? Maybe the real world is such a world, and the Earth stops rotating tonight. Then again, we could have made the same prediction yesterday, or the day before, or any day in the last hundred thousand or so years, and we would be wrong. It would seem that assuming the trend continues is the smart bet, at least in the real world.

In this case, you are picking out ribbons in an idealised, simplified, hypothetical world. The rules of the world are pre-determined: each ribbon has an equal chance of being black or white, regardless of which random order they are drawn. The chance of each ribbon being black or white does not depend on the ribbons around them (e.g. it's not like the black ribbons leak dye onto the white ones, turning random ones black!). The odds of any one ribbon being black are fifty-fifty.

In the real world, if you stumbled across a bag of ribbons, it would be assembled by somebody. If that somebody told you that they constructed this bag only out of black and white ribbons, your pattern-seeking mind might come to the conclusion that they've probably just stuck to a pattern of putting only black ribbons into the bag. This would be a more appropriate use of inductive reasoning.

Comment: For the bag of ribbon case, I think it is more than just induction or pattern seeking, and it may be reasonable to increase the belief that the last ribbon is black. If there is $1$ white ribbon in the bag, there's only $1\%$ probability of having drawn $99$ black ribbons. (Increasing belief does not mean to over $50\%$ probability though.)

Comment: Of course the exact probability depends on the prior belief of how the bag was assembled; for your assumption that the ribbons follow binomial distribution with $p=0.5$, the last ribbon being black has probability $0.5$ now. But before drawing, the relative probabilities of having exactly $1$ white to all black was $100:1$.

Comment: @peterwhy If it's *known* that there's one white ribbon in the bag, then the probability is $0\%$ that the next one is black. If it's not known, then following the binomial distribution assumptions, it will be $50\%$. While there are $100$ times the number of equally likely outcomes where $1$ white ribbon appears in the bag, it is $100$ times less likely that we are in any of these outcomes if we have drawn $99$ black ribbons already. It balances out, and indeed, we are back to fifty-fifty odds, based on the available information.

Comment: True, so my point was that, before and after drawing 99 black ribbons, it is reasonable to increase the belief that the last ribbon is black. It is not always valid to increase the belief to over 50% though.

Comment: Thanks for the reply... But I am not assuming that the chance of picking the ribbons as black or white is 50/50. First of all, I do assume that these are all the ribbons that exist. And that there can be only a black or white ribbon. However, the ratio of them is not assumed.

Comment: In that case, I would say, from a mathematical perspective, the question is not well-defined. Mathematics can't give you an absolute probability of something in the real world. All it can do is analyse hypothetical models. If there's no information about how likely one ribbon is to be chosen over another, then there is not enough information to answer the question.

Comment: The model can still be hypothetical even though one does not know the probability of drawing out either ribbon the since the only factor influencing the probability of choosing one is the (unknown) ratio of the white to black ribbons in the bag. I was thinking that if the last string was white then it would have had a very likely chance of appearing in the 99 ribbons and so it is very unlikely of being white and so the last ribbon is more likely to be black. But I am not sure whether I am right to assume this.

Comment: @PrinceDeepthinker There isn't really a model here. Being "unknown" is not an assumption that we can work from mathematically. "Unknown" is not quite the same thing as "random". For example, the quintillionth digit of $\sqrt{\pi}$ is AFAIK unknown, but it is something definite, and it is not a random variable. It just needs to be investigated (like pulling a ribbon from a bag). It's not quite correct to say it has a $1$ in $10$ chance of being, say, $3$, as it has $100\%$ chance of being one particular digit. We just don't know which particular digit it is!

Comment: @PrinceDeepthinker Again, in the real world, you'd be at least somewhat philosophically justified in thinking that the last ribbon is going to be black. In the mathematical world... well, the question doesn't really exist in the mathematical world. Not only is the probability unknown, there is no answer. If you don't nominate some kind of probability that a ribbon will be black, then there is no probability to know.

Comment: Oh I see it now, yes the uncertainty of the probability remains, regardless of how many ribbons you pull out, and regardless if the number of ribbons are finite (the next ribbon being black could still be either 100% or 0% if is was white instead).

Comment: Yes, exactly!${}$